# Difficulty with changing CSS button with media query

Tags: css, media-queries

This should be basic but I am struggling with it:

My markup is simple:

```
<p>
    <a href="" class="button">sort / search all events in United States</a>
</p>
```

And this CSS works well - BUT - in a small screen there is too much text so I am just trying to lower the size of the font, should be simple enough but I can't get it to work.

```
.button {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family:inherit;
  color: #393939 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #c8d6e5;
  padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
  border: solid #ffffff 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #9facb5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
        
@media screen and (min-width: 1251px) {
 .button {
font-size: 12px !important;
 }
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@media screen and (min-width: 1251px)` will only apply styles at `1251px` wide *and up*. If you want to apply styles to smaller screens only, you'll need to use `max-width` instead, which has the opposite effect.

Alternatively, you could apply the smaller font size by default without a media query, and then use the `min-width` query to *increase* the size at larger widths.